# Passing multiple values in an SSRS URL

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an issue with passing multiple values in an SSRS URL.

```
http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMOS%2fMOS_Test&rs:Command=Render&Cluster=Manchester&Borough=Manchester&Section=S111%20-%20Wyt
```

Above is what i'm using as the URL. Each of the parameters links to a drop down, the first parameter sets the drop down fine, but the rest don't and are blank(you can still click them and make a selection). Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

The report was created in VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to know why just with a link, the link seems correct from what I can see.
try switching around the parameters to know if it's because it only sees the first parameter or it isn't that it doesn't see specific parameters.
my bet is that the other selects don't contain the value you pass to them, make sure that there is no whitespace or other tedious issues that wouldn't make them equal to each other.